# How do I set my MX records to point to Bluehost when my site is registered with Namecheap but hosted with AWS?

Tags: web-hosting, email, amazon-aws, email-address, bluehost

A quick back story on my case here as its a bit complicated:
I bought a domain on Namecheap and hosted with Bluehost on a 3-year plan. But I decided to move the website to AWS and its up and running better there now.
However, I need to configure email addresses and it becomes a complication as BlueHost wants me to configure MX record on Namecheap but Namecheap wants me to change my DNS to their default to get such access.

How do I go about setting up my emails (`name@example.com`) in this scenario?

My DNS is hosted with AWS
Domain is registered with Namecheap
So I guess the question now is how do I set up a mailing server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to do, but remember first you would to install all the aplications in order to run your email server, such as Postfix (the SMTP email server), Dovecot (the IMAP and POP email server), RoundQube, Squirrelmail ... (email visualisation and managing) ...
There are a lot of how to's, here some examples:

- https://speedkills.io/email-server-aws/
- https://www.cloudinsidr.com/content/set-mail-server-aws-ec2-using-open-source-software/

Remember, the EC2 instances uses the elastic IP and will change in every reboot. In order to avoid this issue you can use the Route53 DNS zone manager or use an static IP for the EC2 instance (if is used it's free)

Answer (score 1):

MX records need to be added at your DNS host.     I'm not sure why Bluehost is suggesting adding the MX records at Namecheap.  Since you DNS is hosted at AWS domain, you should add the MX records there.

Namecheap is offering to be your DNS host, but I wouldn't advise doing that.  It is usually best to use AWS Route 53 to host your DNS when you are using other AWS services.   AWS DNS has special records that work easily with their load balancers and CDNs.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Ostermiller. Are you saying I should transfer the domain to AWS? Already I have moved my website to AWS and changed my DNS to the ones AWS gave. I think having BlueHost in the mix is what is creating the confusion.

The only challenge here now is updating MX record on namecheap as there is no option for that unless I changed my DNS to namecheap' .

So maybe a workmail will help me out here

Comment: Using Namecheap as a DNS registrar is fine. The only thing you need to set at Namecheap is NS records that point AWS.  Then in the AWS DNS (they call it route 53)  you need to set your MX records pointing to Bluehost. You can't set your MX records at Namecheap when Amazon's handling your DNS.

Comment: I get it, thanks for your answers